# Will HTML 5 specify a way to get the client's location and culture info?

Tags: ajax, web-services, internationalization, standards, geolocation

I have this web service... It serves up HTML in response to an AJAX request, and the web service needs to be aware of:

1. the user's specific language
2. the user's timezone or location

I understand that this is currently quite infeasible. BUT...

It seems that HTML 5 will have a [Geolocation API!](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-geolocation-API-20081222/)  Awesome. This should take care of my timezone requirement (I can just look it up in a database somehow).

However, I would also like to know how to get their culture settings ("en-US", etc.) so I can render DateTimes and numbers from my web service to their specific preferences.

---

Note: this is a follow-up question to my other question: [Finding the client's timezone and culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017053)

Comment: You should reread the link you posted. It's not part of HTML 5, and it's only a working draft.

Comment: Sorry, I beg to differ: http://radar.oreilly.com/2009/05/google-bets-big-on-html-5.html  And historically, the W3C works forever on the Working Draft while browsers implement it.  The concern I have is, will future browser tech (in the umbrella of HTML 5 support) do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the HTTP header now - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4 - every language has a way to get this information.  Which language is your web service implemented in?

Comment: I have a .NET web service.  In any case, thanks for your link - that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong places like the ECMAscript and HTML specs and browser-specific extensions.  (Next time, I'll remember to look at HTTP, duh!)