# How to do timezones in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timezone

On my site, I need to know what timezones people are located in, in order to display messages to them at the right times.  I am not too sure what to be searching for in terms of a tutorial on how to do this.

What I am planning on doing is: when a user comes to my site, they will set their timezone by selecting it from a dropdown list. I will store their settings in my database and use it to calculate the times.

I am not sure what I need.  What should be my database time be storing?  I read somewhere that it should be stored as UTC.  How do I set up my database to do this?  Also, I will be on a shared hosting site so it has to be set in a way that I can do it (maybe through webconfig?).

Next, I would need a list of all the timezones as either an HTML helper or regular HTML. I really don't want to make one.

Then, like I said, I need a tutorial showing me what to do. I think it is adding and subtracting stuff from that time, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For this purpose, you should definitely be storing your timestamps in UTC in the database.

When you need to display a date from the database on your site, you can do this:

```
DateTime stamp = /* get datetime from the database here, make sure you
                    use the constructor that allows you to specify the 
                    DateTimeKind as UTC. */

//E.g.
//DateTime stamp = new DateTime(2009, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, DateTimeKind.Utc);

timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(" /* users time zone here */"); 
var convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(stamp, timeZoneInfo);

//Print out the date and time
//Console.WriteLine(convertedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"));
```

The list of timezones is already available in .Net, so you can see [this post on how to enumerate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442019/how-do-i-enumerate-all-time-zones-in-net).  For ASP.Net MVC, instead of printing the time out, you would want to assign the converted datetime to a property of your model class so your View could use it for display.

Comment: Hi Thanks I will start trying to implement this. I have another unknown. Is the user comes to my site and I want to go through the db and see what messages they to display base on their timezone. So would I first figure out what their time is and then convert it to UTC? then do a where with it? So sort of reverse what your doing in your example?

Comment: Well, initially you mentioned allowing the user to set their timezone.  However, there are a number of methods of discovering the user's timezone via javascript, you could search around stackoverflow for more info, for example this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017053/finding-the-clients-timezone-and-culture-via-web-service

Comment: I am fine with them choosing their timezone and don't really want to look into javascript right now. I am just saying would that be how I would start looking for specific dates in my db? By trying to convert back to UTF?

Comment: I was just trying to get your stuff to run and um "Kind" is readOnly.

Comment: Ah, correct you are, forgot about that.  You have to specify it when you construct your DateTime object initially.  For example, DateTime time = new DateTime(2009, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, DateTimeKind.Utc);.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hey I been thinking do I even need to know their timezone? I am just wonering if I store everything in UTC in my database and they come to my site can't I just go DateTime.Utc and it will give me the utc time? then I just use that to search my dtabase? Or would this give me the Utc time of the server?

Answer (score 9):

I cannot stress how important it is to use UTC for storage and processing for any application you write.  Even if you know the application will ever only be used in a single timezone it is still much easier to work with UTC than a local timezone because of daylight saving time issues.

There's really nothing special you need to do at the database level.  Just create a normal datetime column, but make sure it is documented clearly that the column is assumed to be UTC.

I'll be honest, asp.net isn't my expertise, but I'm thinking you could obtain the timezone from the client request somehow.  Actually, because the daylight saving time rules can be pretty obscure depending on the region it might be better to use a java script that calculates the UTC offset and use that to make the conversions.  Even after the *Energy Policy Act of 2005* there are still some exceptions to the DST rules that would rather hard to deal with on the server side.  However, I think you're idea of allowing the client to set their own timezone would work well in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

First, check MSDN for DateTime documentation and read up on it. [Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx) on Best Practices with DateTime that covers timezones and UTC.

Yes, you should be storing UTC in your database. Storing DateTimes as UTC will allow you to translate times to (and from) users based on their selected timezone. You're on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

**Usage**

```
getCurrentDateTimeWithTimeZone("Central Europe Standard Time");
```

**Method**

```
public DateTime getCurrentDateTimeWithTimeZone(string strTimeZone)
    {
        var localTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        var userTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strTimeZone);

        var todayDate = DateTime.Now;
        var todayLocal = new DateTimeOffset(todayDate,
                                            localTimezone.GetUtcOffset(todayDate));

        var todayUserOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(todayLocal, userTimezone);
        return todayUserOffset.DateTime;

    }
```

**List of Timezone ID**

> Dateline Standard Time
>
> UTC-11
>
> Samoa Standard Time
>
> Hawaiian Standard Time
>
> Alaskan Standard Time
>
> Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
>
> Pacific Standard Time
>
> US Mountain Standard Time
>
> Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)
>
> Mountain Standard Time
>
> Central America Standard Time
>
> Central Standard Time
>
> Central Standard Time (Mexico)
>
> Canada Central Standard Time
>
> SA Pacific Standard Time
>
> Eastern Standard Time
>
> US Eastern Standard Time
>
> Venezuela Standard Time
>
> Paraguay Standard Time
>
> Atlantic Standard Time
>
> Central Brazilian Standard Time
>
> SA Western Standard Time
>
> Pacific SA Standard Time
>
> Newfoundland Standard Time
>
> E. South America Standard Time
>
> Argentina Standard Time
>
> SA Eastern Standard Time
>
> Greenland Standard Time
>
> Montevideo Standard Time
>
> UTC-02
>
> Mid-Atlantic Standard Time
>
> Azores Standard Time
>
> Cape Verde Standard Time
>
> Morocco Standard Time
>
> UTC
>
> GMT Standard Time
>
> Greenwich Standard Time
>
> W. Europe Standard Time
>
> Central Europe Standard Time
>
> Romance Standard Time
>
> Central European Standard Time
>
> W. Central Africa Standard Time
>
> Namibia Standard Time
>
> Jordan Standard Time
>
> GTB Standard Time
>
> Middle East Standard Time
>
> Egypt Standard Time
>
> Syria Standard Time
>
> South Africa Standard Time
>
> FLE Standard Time
>
> Israel Standard Time
>
> E. Europe Standard Time
>
> Arabic Standard Time
>
> Arab Standard Time
>
> Russian Standard Time
>
> E. Africa Standard Time
>
> Iran Standard Time
>
> Arabian Standard Time
>
> Azerbaijan Standard Time
>
> Mauritius Standard Time
>
> Georgian Standard Time
>
> Caucasus Standard Time
>
> Afghanistan Standard Time
>
> Ekaterinburg Standard Time
>
> Pakistan Standard Time
>
> West Asia Standard Time
>
> India Standard Time
>
> Sri Lanka Standard Time
>
> Nepal Standard Time
>
> Central Asia Standard Time
>
> Bangladesh Standard Time
>
> N. Central Asia Standard Time
>
> Myanmar Standard Time
>
> SE Asia Standard Time
>
> North Asia Standard Time
>
> China Standard Time
>
> North Asia East Standard Time
>
> Singapore Standard Time
>
> W. Australia Standard Time
>
> Taipei Standard Time
>
> Ulaanbaatar Standard Time
>
> Tokyo Standard Time
>
> Korea Standard Time
>
> Yakutsk Standard Time
>
> Cen. Australia Standard Time
>
> AUS Central Standard Time
>
> E. Australia Standard Time
>
> AUS Eastern Standard Time
>
> West Pacific Standard Time
>
> Tasmania Standard Time
>
> Vladivostok Standard Time
>
> Central Pacific Standard Time
>
> New Zealand Standard Time
>
> UTC+12
>
> Fiji Standard Time
>
> Kamchatka Standard Time
>
> Tonga Standard Time