# Store GMT dates on a US server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, shared-hosting, gmt

I'm from the UK, and have recently deployed a website on WinHost's [Basic Package](http://www.winhost.com/windows-hosting-plans-basic.aspx).

When using `DateTime.Now()` in C#, or `GETDATE()` in SQL, these are both returning something like `GMT-8` (because the server is hosted in the US).

I think I'm a bit limited in terms of permissions on the server (for example I can't change my SQL Login Language).

What is the best method of storing these dates in GMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

I think you should store your DateTimes in UTC. Then you can simple convert it to another Timezone with the TimezoneInfo class.

- Save `DateTime.UtcNow` to your database or use `getUtcDate` inside sql
- Let the user choose his timezone and save them to to your database
- Convert the UTC Time you have saved to the users timezone using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`

#### Sample

```
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(/* destination timezone (users timezone)  */);
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(YourDateTimeFromDatabase, cstZone);
```

#### More Information

- [How to do timezones? In asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320048/how-to-do-timezones-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [MSDN - TimeZoneInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)

Comment: I've just looked up UTC, and it states `Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer`. By "this computer", I'm assuming its referring to the shared server?

Comment: right.. it reads the datetime of the server.. And since you read back the data from the same server, it should not be an issue.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow is the UTC time. It gets calculated in relation to the servers time. So if your server is up to date, .net can calculate the right utc.

Answer (score 4):

use `DateTime.UtcNow` and store as it is database.
When reading from database assume `UTC` and convert into `UK` time using `TimeZoneInfo` class.
Note that the SQL should not contain any information about time zone offsets.

Answer (score 3):

In SqlServer use getUtcDate() to store all your datetime values. You can convert it to required timezone in your .NET application.